# onSubmit event not getting triggered in NEXT JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js

I am using next js with redux.

I am trying to submit a form that is nested in a modal.
The Modal body is dynamic and changes by the state value in redux.

```
'use client';

import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'


const modalDisplaySlice = createSlice({
    name : 'modalDisplay',
    initialState: {
        value: 'hidden',
    },
    reducers: {
        showModal : state => {state.value = ''},
        hideModal : state => {state.value = 'hidden'}
    }
});

export const {showModal, hideModal} = modalDisplaySlice.actions;
export const modalDisplayReducer = modalDisplaySlice.reducer;





let CreateRoomModal = () =>
{
    let createNewSpace = (evt) => 
    {
        evt.preventDefault();
        console.log('OK');
    }

    return (
        <div className="flex">
            <div className="basis-full">
                <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold bg-slate-800 p-4 text-white">Create Space</h1>    
                <form onSubmit={createNewSpace} className="flex flex-col p-5 md:w-10/12 w-full mx-auto">
                    <div className="mb-2 text-center">
                        <input type="text" className="px-2 py-3 border-b border-slate-800 focus:outline-0 w-full" name="organizer" placeholder="Enter you Name"/>
                    </div> 
                    <div className="text-end p-2">
                        <input type="submit" className="bg-orange-500 p-2 text-white md:text-lg text-md hover:bg-orange-600 focus:text-black" value="Create Space"/>   
                    </div>                                                                                              
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

let JoinRoomModal = () => 
{
    return (
        <div className="flex">
            <div className="basis-full">
                <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold bg-slate-800 p-4 text-white">Join Space</h1>    
                <form className="flex flex-col p-5 md:w-10/12 w-full mx-auto">
                    <div className="mb-2 text-center">
                       <input type="text" className="px-2 py-3 border-b border-slate-800 focus:outline-0 w-full" placeholder="Enter Auth Token"/>
                    </div> 
                    <div className="mb-2 text-center">
                        <input type="text" className="px-2 py-3 border-b border-slate-800 focus:outline-0 w-full" placeholder="Enter your Name"/>
                    </div> 
                    <div className="basis-10/12 text-end p-2">
                        <button className="bg-orange-500 p-2 text-white md:text-lg text-md hover:bg-orange-600">Join Space</button>  
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>    
    );
} 


const modalContentSlice = createSlice({
    name : 'modalContent',
    initialState: {
        value: '',
    },
    reducers: {
        setContent : (state, modal) => {
            switch (modal.payload)
            {
                case 'createRoomModal':
                    state.value = <CreateRoomModal/>;
                break;

                case 'joinRoomModal':
                    state.value = <JoinRoomModal/>;
                break;
            }
        }       
    }
});

export const {setContent} = modalContentSlice.actions;
export const modalContentReducer = modalContentSlice.reducer;
```

When I try to submit the form, It gives no error, but the console.log statement is also not executed.

When I checked for the event listeners on the developer tool, Its shows no event listeners attached on on Submit form

[image]

Although, Button onClick event is working as expected.